# Why do I get this compile error when using InputComponents in UE4?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I'm following this [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Tutorials/PlayerInput/3/index.html), but it doesn't compile cause of "InputComponent". Unfortunately the error is not that clear even in my language.

Here's the error:

> CompilerResultsLog: Error: C:\Users\Paradisee\Desktop\C++\Paper\Source\Paper\PlayerTile.cpp(83) : note: I tipi a cui si punta sono privi di relazioni. La conversione richiede reinterpret_cast, cast di tipo C o cast di tipo funzione
>   CompilerResultsLog: ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: C:\Users\Paradisee\Desktop\C++\Paper\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-Paper-583.dll

Here's the code:

```
// Called to bind functionality to input
void APlayerTile::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Respond every frame to the values of our two movement axes, "MoveX" and "MoveY".
    InputComponent->BindAction("MoveX", IE_Pressed, this, &APlayerTile::MoveX);
    InputComponent->BindAction("MoveY", IE_Pressed, this, &APlayerTile::MoveY);
}
```

This is the definition of the method MoveX():

```
void APlayerTile::MoveX(float AxisValue)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BindAction` expects to take a `FInputActionHandlerSignature::TUObjectMethodDelegate<UserClass>::FMethodPtr` as the last parameter. This is, basically, a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing. In other words, something like:

```
void APlayerTile::MoveX() {
  ...
}
```

You're giving it a function that takes a float parameter:

```
void APlayerTile::MoveX(float AxisValue) {
  ...
}
```

Pointers to those functions don't match because they have different signatures, and cannot be implicitly converted. The error is telling you that: that if you want to force this conversion you must use a C-style cast or a `reinterpret_cast`, which would make the code compile (but crash or otherwise misbehave at runtime, so that's not a solution).

You either need to change your `MoveX` so it doesn't take a parameter, or use `BindAxis` to bind it instead of `BindAction`. `BindAxis` is for "axis" inputs, which have a value associated with them representing their current state. `BindAction` is for "action" inputs, which don't have continuous values but rather are either "pressed" or "released."

Comment: shouldn't be the method be called every frame if the key is pressed? Cause it is not happening to me.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. "Pressed" and "Released" actions trigger only when the key combination associated with the action is first pressed or first released.

Comment: If you want to move continously, you need to use `bindAxis()` and not `bindAction()`

Comment: Well, my intention is to make my player move in a single direction when the game begins without pressing nothing, and be able to move constantly to other directions if he press once only. Like the game "Paper-io.io"

Comment: If you're unsure how to do that using the UE axis/action inputs, you should post a new question about it.